# how to create where clause query in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How should i call this method having string as parameter or how should i execute this query??

Code:

```
public class Samsung extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_samsung);        
        Intent intent = getIntent();       
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> SamsungList = getSamsungInfo(null);
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Samsung.this, SamsungList, R.layout.samsung_list, new String[] {Sqlite.COLUMN_MNAME, Sqlite.COLUMN_MMODEL,
                             Sqlite.COLUMN_MPRICE,Sqlite.COLUMN_MCAMERA} , new int[] {R.id.nameofsamsung, R.id.modelofsamsung, R.id.priceofsamsung, R.id.cameraofsamsung});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }  

public ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>> getSamsungInfo(String samsung) { 
    ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList= new ArrayList <HashMap<String, String>>();
    Sqlite sqlll = new Sqlite(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = sqlll.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname="+samsung+"'";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(Sqlite.COLUMN_MNAME, cursor.getString(0));
                map.put(Sqlite.COLUMN_MMODEL, cursor.getString(1));
                map.put(Sqlite.COLUMN_MPRICE, cursor.getString(2));
                map.put(Sqlite.COLUMN_MCAMERA, cursor.getString(3));
                wordList. add(map);                                
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }                  
return wordList ;
}  
}
```

It is giving me error that there is no column named "null". So what should i pass while calling method. it is not taking samsung which is the inserted value in column mname of mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote your literals in SQL:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname='"+samsung+"'";
```

though it's better to use bind args, like this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname=?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { samsung });
```

Also, pass in an actual argument to `getSamsungInfo()` instead of `null`.

Comment: It is not allowed.. Asking me to create locale variable "samsung". and if i ll create, it will be null ified.

Comment: It's a method argument, see `getSamsungInfo(String samsung)` - you need to change the part where you call that method with `getSamsungInfo(null)`

Comment: In call method: Instead of getSamsungInfo(null), what sholud i do?? its not taking anythng else...

Comment: As u said above.. if i am doing getSamsungInfo(), then it is showing error in this line: Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { samsung }); ERROR: CREATE LOCAL VARIABLE SAMSUNG.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is wrong:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname="+samsung+"'";
```

It should be (correct apostrophes to surround the string value):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname = 'samsung'";
```

OR, better (here I use a variable),

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname = '" + mobileName + "'";
```

where mobileName is a passed string which contains (for instance) "samsung"

OR, even much better (bound argument),

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE mname = ?";
```

followed by:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {mobileName});
```

where mobileName is a passed string which contains (for instance) "samsung" - the same as before
here `null` is replaced by the string argument

Comment: I have tried but while calling getSamsungInfo, I am passing null so again it is showing this error.